# Dynamic page Titles

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have this class for page titles:

```
class UI {

    private static $title;

    public static function getTitle() { return self::$title; }
    public static function setTitle($value) { self::$title = $value; }
    }
```

So in my frontpage I simple declare this:

```
UI::setTitle('Kiubbo.com :: Todas las Noticias, Fotos y Videos');
```

And works fine. The problem is to get the comments pages titles to change depending on the content (title of links). I want to be the same as this variable (that has the same name but it its for another function its not the same getTitle):

```
<?php echo $article->getTitle(); ?>
```

Which its in this function:

```
function showAllComments($article_id, $param)
    {

        $article = Article::getById($article_id);

        if(!empty($article))
        {
            ?>
            <div class="news_item">
                <h2 class="news_item_title"><b><a href = "<?php echo $article->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $article->getTitle(); ?></a></b></h2>              

            </div>
```

If anyone can help I appreciate it.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you want to do.  If you want each object to have a separate title, then you need to make the title variable non-static (and the functions non-static as well).  A static variable/function has only one instance per class.

Answer (score 1):

change " $article->getTitle() " to " UI::getTitle() " and it should work, but I don't think that is what you really want to do, is it?

Answer (score 1):

In `showAllComments()` maybe you could do

```
UI::setTitle($article->getTitle());
```

Comment: I have try it but does not work. Probably the header is build before the showAllComments function.

Comment: yeah that makes sense. Maybe showAllComments() could take an instance of Article rather than article_id , then you can fetch it outside the function and before outputting any HTML